# How to transfer a mutex containing object from one function to another?

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns

```
#include <mutex>

class ConcurrentQueue {
    // This class contains a queue and contains functions push to the queue and pop from the queue done in a thread safe manner.
    std::mutex m;
};

class Producer {
    // This class contains several methods which take some ConcurrentQueue objects and then schedule tasks onto it.
public:
    void func(ConcurrentQueue a) {}
};

class Consumer {
    // This class contains several methods which take the same ConcurrentQueue objects and then remove the tasks and complete them one by one.
public:
    void func(ConcurrentQueue a) {}
};

int main() {
    // Here I want to generate the necessary ConcurrentQueue objects and then start threads for producer and consumer methods where I supply it with the required queue objects.
    ConcurrentQueue a;
    Producer b;

    // :( Unfortunately I cannot pass in any of my ConcurrentQueue objects to the methods as apparantly I cannot copy transfer a mutex.
    b.func(a); // This line gives compiler error saying the copy constructor is deleted.
    
    return 0;
}
```

The above code explains the whole situation through comments. How do I design it better so that I am able to achieve this?

Comment: Do you know what `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` are, and how to use them?

Comment: Considering that `Producer::func` and `Consumer::func` have return type `void`, it sounds like you want to be passing them a `ConcurrentQueue&` reference so that changes made to the object inside the bodies of `func` are reflected afterward.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik yes I do, but I dont understand how that could be used in this situation.

Comment: `std::mutex` is non-copyable, non-assignable, so that makes the same for any other object that has it as a class member. But a `std::unique_ptr` or a `std::shared_ptr`, to such an object, does not have this limitation, of course.

Comment: @NathanPierson even changing the signature to `void func(ConcurrentQueue &a) {}` did not work. I tried that already.

Comment: A class with a `std::mutex` is not copyable and not moveable. The quick fix is to have a `std::unique_ptr<std::mutex> n = std::make_unique<std::mutex>();` member. Then at least the class is moveable. If you want it to be copyable as well, you need to implement the [rule of 5](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). However, in this case, it seems like simply passing the `ConcurrentQueue` should be possible, meaning it doesn't have to be copyable or moveable. Since you expressed that you want to share the queue between threads, passing by reference is mandatory.

Comment: When you say "did not work", what happened instead?

Comment: @NathanPierson Same error was thrown by the compiler. Nothing changed.

Comment: I [cannot reproduce](https://godbolt.org/z/d8oTrW4hr) when I change to passing by reference. Can you please show the version with passing by reference that does not compile?

Comment: Did you change both `Producer::func` and `Consumer::func`?

Comment: What is the topic of the chapter in your C++ textbook that this practice problem is from? This will be helpful in pointing you towards the expected solution (since it must be related to that topic).

Comment: @NathanPierson My bad, I changed only one of them. It is working now. Sorry.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik This is not a C++ textbook problem. Its an MCVE created for the asking here. I was getting this problem in my project.

Comment: Well, I'm afraid that the real answer, here, is to invest in a good textbook and study up on these C++ fundamental concepts. Unfortunately, Stackoverflow doesn't really work as a replacement for a C++ textbook. As far as the answer to the original question: you can't "transfer a mutex containing object", for the reasons that were already explained, C++ does not work this way. Either references, or smart pointers must be used. S good C++ textbook will have a complete discussion of these topics.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want your ConcurrentQueue class to be copyable, then don't pass it by value; use pass-by-reference (i.e. arguments of types `const ConcurrentQueue &` or `ConcurrentQueue &`) instead.

OTOH if you actually *want* your ConcurrentQueue class to be copyable (and you should carefully consider whether or not allowing the copying of a ConcurrentQueue object would be helpful or harmful to your goals), you can simply add a copy-constructor to your ConcurrentQueue class that copies the other member-variables but doesn't try to copy the std::mutex:

```
class ConcurrentQueue {
    // This class contains a queue and contains functions push to the queue and pop from the queue done in a thread safe manner.
    std::mutex m;
    std::queue<int> q;

public:
    ConcurrentQueue()
    {
       // default constructor
    }

    ConcurrentQueue(const ConcurrentQueue & rhs)
    {
       // serialize access to rhs.q so we can read its 
       // contents safely while copying them into this->q
       const std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(const_cast<std::mutex &>(rhs.m));
       q = rhs.q;
    }
};
```

Note that I needed to add a default-constructor as well, since once you add any kind of constructor to the class, the compiler will no longer automatically create a default-constructor for you anymore.  If you're using C++11 or later, you could declare the default-constructor via `ConcurrentQueue() = default;` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Although Jeremy Friesner has given some good information, I think it's worth adding some advice that's a little more direct.

In this case you almost certainly do *not* want to copy any queue. If you copy a queue, you'll end up with the producer putting data into one queue, and the consumer trying to get data from an entirely separate queue. For what you seem to be trying to accomplish, that's not going to accomplish anything useful.

For a producer/consumer situation, you almost always want a single queue, so the producer can push data into the queue and the consumer will retrieve data from that same queue.

That leaves three options for how to do things:

- Producer owns queue, consumer gets a reference to the queue.
- Consumer owns queue, producer gets a reference to the queue.
- Parent of both owns queue, passes reference to both producer and consumer.

[note: in this case, "reference" could really mean "pointer".]

At least at first, I'd generally advise the last of these. This keeps lifetime management fairly easy. Especially if the producer owns the queue, the initial temptation is for the producer to be destroyed after it finishes its job, but you need to assure the queue isn't destroyed until the consumer has consumed all the data, so you need a side-channel backward from the consumer to the producer to signal when the queue can be destroyed.

When the parent creates the queue, about all it has to do is define an instance of the queue, and pass it to the producer and the consumer. Then after they're done it returns (or whatever) and the queue gets destroyed more or less automatically, but not until both children are done with it.

Comment: There's also "give a `std::shared_ptr<ConcurrentQueue>` to anyone who wants it, and let reference-counting sort out the queue's lifetime"

Comment: @JeremyFriesner: There is, but (at least in my experience) for a case like this, it's rarely necessary (or helpful).